# Your changes could not be saved. Please try again. (-32600) in Linked Apps

Tags: google-play-games

I'm Trying to modify information in the Linked Apps section of Google Play Games Services in the Developer console. Things such as translated titles and whether or not the game uses anti-piracy or not.

It is coming up with the following error every time:

```
Your changes could not be saved. Please try again. (-32600)
```

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're logged in to the above console using account 1, and later tried accessing the console from another Google Account. I faced the same issue and was resolved once I was logged back in to the correct account